# A way to copy and store all entries in a balanced binary search tree with O(1)

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I am implementing a binary search tree in C++11. I want to add a feature that makes it possible to mark different versions of the data structure with constant time complexity.

What I thought about was to add another property to the root node called "name", "key" or "mark"  - thus being accessible with O(1). But to save the tree version I would have to

1. create a copy of the root (I thought of creating a new instance of the binary search tree and simply assign the tree I want to copy to this new instance)
2. store the copied root in an array

It is sufficient if those stored roots have read-access only. But now my question is: Can I perform these 2 steps without adding time complexity?

Below there is a little sketch illustrating the process.

[image]

Thank you very much for your help.

FunkyPeanut

Comment: I don't follow this.  If you're creating a new version of the tree, why do you need to copy all of the roots of the old versions?  Can you add a diagram or something, showing what your intent is?

Comment: Hey. I added a little sketch. I hope it helps! 

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean. I didn't mean to write "each root" ... I think I've meant to say "the root of each tree you want to copy". I'll fix the issue. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're after is a [persistent BST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure#Trees). This allows "copying" in O(1) time (just copy a pointer), while performing all the other BST operations with the same big-O times as the vanilla BST. The main difference is that operations that used to take O(1) space now take up to O(lg n) space, at least when the old version of the tree has been stored somewhere.

(You can implement persistent data structures in C++ quite easily with `shared_ptr`.)

Comment: Hmm... this is a pretty interesting data structure you presented. Could you elaborate more on why the time complexity rises when the old version is stored? Is it just because there is a lookup time to be considered? Even if it is inserted in an array where lookup runs in O(1)?

Comment: @FunkyPeanut: the *space* complexity changes. That's because you need to re-construct part of the tree, separately from the old structure. Ordinarily, you would then throw part of the old tree away (and you can set it up to do this with only constant extra space), but when you store a pointer to the old tree somewhere, all of it has to remain in memory.

Comment: Okay Sure that makes sense. Thanks fort that.